# Pass function parameters with time based triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function makeRequest(facebookAccountData). The parameter is an object. They key value pairs are retrieved from the HTML and stored in the object.

Now I want to schedule this trigger lets say every day at 8 am. After every 5 minutes is just to test the code.  I tried doing like this but this doesn't work.

How can I pass the parameter with this function below.

Steps:
1- Users will select the facebook fields that they want data for such as impressions, clicks and etc.

2- That data is retrieved from the HTML and then stored into an object and then object is passed as a parameter into makeRequest function.

3- Once it gets the data from the API, it will paste the data into sheet as per pasteDataSheet function.

4- I want to automate the query every day at 8 am or with different scenarios. Instead of doing it manually.

**HTML**

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",retrieveData);
  
  function retrieveData () {

    var facebookAccountData = {};
    var fields =    $('#fieldsData').val();
    var accountId = $('#accountData').val();

    facebookAccountData.startDate = document.getElementById('select').value;
    facebookAccountData.adAccount = accountId
    facebookAccountData.facebookFields = fields   
    google.script.run.makeRequest(facebookAccountData);
    
  }
```

**Code.gs**

```
function makeRequest(facebookAccountData) {
   
  // API Logic goes here
  
  ....

 
  
    //set up the API Endpoint

   
  
  const base = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/';
  
  const endpoint = 'act_' +facebookAccountData.adAccount+ '/insights?' + '&fields=' + facebookAccountData.facebookFields + '&date_preset=' + facebookAccountData.startDate + '&level=ad' + '&time_increment=1'
  
  const url = base + endpoint;
  console.log(url);

  const params = {

    headers: {

      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    }
    
  }
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
  console.log(response);

  const data = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(data);
  
     pasteDataToSheet (data);
  
}

function pasteDataToSheet (data) {

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const headers = Object.keys(data.data[0]);
console.log(headers);
// const values = [headers, ...data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]))];

var values = data.data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h]));
if (sheet.getLastRow() == 0) values.unshift(headers);

console.log(values);

}


ScriptApp.newTrigger("makeRequest")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
```

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to a trigger.  You could JSON.stringify the object and retrieve it from properties service, parse it and use it that way.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "They key value pairs are retrieved from the HTML and stored in the object". Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.Thank you.

Comment: Where  is `makeRequest` function ? And what is your intention every 5 minutes? What data are you wanting to pass into the function? As in your HTML you have someone inputting the data into the form.

Comment: @Aerials I have update the question with more details. This will give you a complete picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when you install a time trigger like in your example you can't tell the function which parameter to pass to the function.

One way to capture the user's selection is to use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()) to store the user's selections in an object. (as suggested by Cooper you can use  `JSON.stringify`).

You should also use a default value for the `facebookAccountData` parameter, so that it would fetch the property stored for the user.

#### Example:

Your HTML changes to this:

```html
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",retrieveData);
function retrieveData () {
    var facebookAccountData = {};
    var fields =    $('#fieldsData').val();
    var accountId = $('#accountData').val();
    facebookAccountData.startDate = document.getElementById('select').value;
    facebookAccountData.adAccount = accountId
    facebookAccountData.facebookFields = fields;
    google.script.run.storeOptionsAndInstallTrigger(facebookAccountData);
    google.script.run.makeRequest();    
  }
```

Your Code.gs changes to this:

```js
function storeOptionsAndInstallTrigger(facebookAccountData) {
  // Store the user's input
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('facebookAccountData', JSON.stringify(facebookAccountData));
  // Install the trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("makeRequest")
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(5)
    .create();
}
function makeRequest() {
  let facebookAccountData = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('facebookAccountData'));
  // Do your thing here...
}
```